# Calling dispose() when passing a subscriber that overrides onSubscribe

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java3

I am new to RxJava and if I understand correctly the `Observer` is passed the `Disposable` on the `onSubscribe` so it can manually stop the processing if the `dispose()` has already been called.
I created the following code:

```
@NonNull Observable<Long> src = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
src.subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
      private Disposable d;

      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
           this.d = d;
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(@NonNull Long aLong) {
           if(!d.isDisposed()) {
              System.out.println("Number onNext = " + aLong);
           }
      }

       @Override
       public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onComplete() {
           System.out.println("completed");
       }
 });
```

but I can't figure out how to call `dispose()` for that subscription. `subscribe` with passing `Observer` as an argument returns `void` and `subscribeWith` does not accept my `Observer` without compile errors.

How is this supposed to work? What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JavaDocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html) of `Observable` has a straightforward example:

```java
Disposable d = Observable.just("Hello world!")
     .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
         @Override public void onStart() {
             System.out.println("Start!");
         }
         @Override public void onNext(String t) {
             System.out.println(t);
         }
         @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
             t.printStackTrace();
         }
         @Override public void onComplete() {
             System.out.println("Done!");
         }
     });

 Thread.sleep(500);
 // the sequence can now be disposed via dispose()
 d.dispose();
```

**Edit**

The following examples are ways to get the `Disposable` out of the `onSubscribe` method but are generally not recommended:

```java
// field in the owner class
Disposable disposable;

public void doReactive() {
    Observable<Long> src = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    src.subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
           disposable = d;
        }

        // ...
    });
}

public void cleanup() {
   if (disposable != null) {
       disposable.dispose();
       disposable = null;
   }
}
```

or

```java
SerialDisposable sd = new SerialDisposable();

Observable<Long> src = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    src.subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
           sd.set(d);
        }

        // ...
    });

// ...

sd.dispose();
```

Comment: So then why is the `Disposable` passed as argument on the `onSubscribe` of the `Observer` if I can't do anything with it?

Comment: It has advanced usages such as implementing operators. For an end-consumer, you are better off with `DisposableObserver` or one of the lambda-subscribe methods.

Comment: And when would I use `DisposableObserver` with `subscribe`? I see you use `subscribeWith` which returns the disposable but `subscribe` returns `void`

Comment: You can `new` up the `DisposableObserver` upfront, assign it to a local variable and hand it to the `subscribe` method too.

Comment: But what is the difference with `subscribeWith`? Is it just a more convenient method to avoid doing what you decribed? Because even if I keep the local reference I would not be able to do `dispose()`

Comment: `subscribeWith` returns its input parameter, `subscribe` does not. The former is a [convenience](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.java#L13183-L13186) over the latter. You'd have to put that `Disposable` of `onSubscribe` somewhere that is accessible from outside.

Comment: Your answers helps a lot! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DisposableObserver which can be easily disposed when you are done observing.

```
@NonNull Observable<Long> src = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    src.subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(@NotNull Long aLong) {
            //Do anything you want to do..
            dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NotNull Throwable e) {
            //Handle the errors here..
            dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            dispose();
        }
    });
```

You can also use CompositeDisposable to dispose many observers at one time, For more details check this out.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rxjava/rxjava_compositedisposable.htm

Comment: So the problem is that I am using the base class?

Comment: You can try this, See if this achieves what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That `subscribe` passing `DisposableObserver` has as return type `void`. So how is the `dispose()` supposed to be called then for that observer?